# why my code not working on ie11 after i use babel-polyfill?

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning vue.js , everything works fine on chrome. but on ie11, it doesn't parsing the {{}} tag.

And after i use npm to install babel-polyfill,and used it as a  tag on my page, the problem remains.

here are some of my code.

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="/node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js"
></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/vue/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
      return {
        jobsData: null,
        count: 0,
        total: 0,
        ls: 0,
        le: 15
      };
    },

    mounted() {
      axios
        .get("/activity/gqzq/AjaxGetList?ls=" + this.ls + "&le=" + this.le)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.jobsData = response.data.data;
          this.total = response.data.total;
          this.count = response.data.count;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  });
</script>

<div class="result" v-for="job in jobsData">
  <div class="job job-real" data-i="1" v-if="!job.has_next">
    <div class="title">
      <a
        target="_blank"
        :title="job.title"
        :href="'/jobs/detail/' + job.id + '.html'"
        >{{ job.title }}</a
      ><span class="dates hidden-xs"
        >posttime：{{ job.posttime }} overtime：{{ job.overtime }}</span
      >
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="info_td com_name">
        <a title="" target="_blank" href="/company/detail/9193.html">{{
          job["company.name"]
        }}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="info_td com_type hidden-sm  hidden-xs">
        {{ job["company.type"] }}
      </div>
      <div class="info_td com_location hidden-xs">
        {{ job["company.area"] }}
      </div>
      <div class="info_td posttime hidden-xs">
        {{ job.salary }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

vue suppose to parsing the contents in {{}},but it doesn't. 
so how to fix this and what cause this problem?

Comment: by the way , there's no error in console

Comment: Do you have the console open when the page loads? Internet exploder has a bad habit of not logging if the console is not open. Try location.reload() on the console. There's a very high chance that vue.js itself can't be loaded since it's not transpiled down (es6 classes) .